# Multiple buses routed to different group mixer makes them to share variables in a Render Callback

Tags: ios, callback, core-audio, augraph

I had a render callback with 20 buses synchronized and routed to a same mixer but now I need to apply effects to some of these 20 buses, so now, they are divided into groups of 5.

So now, I have 20 buses divided into 4 groups.

Buses 0-4 -routed to - Mixer1

```
AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (processingGraph,mixer1Node,
                                                  input, //0-4
                                                  &inputCallbackStruct
                                                  );
```

Buses 5-9 -routed to - Mixer2

```
AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (processingGraph,mixer2Node,
                                                  input, //0-4
                                                  &inputCallbackStruct
                                                  );
```

Buses 10-14 -routed to - Mixer3 ...

Buses 15-19 -routed to - Mixer4 ...

Now, my issue is every of these groups are getting [0] to [4] inBusNumber, with the same data in the render callback. So the old inBusNumber [5] now is [0] of Mixer2, with the same render data of bus [0] of Mixer1. All the variables are now shared with buses of the other Mixers.

Now my complex render code is useless .... I need independent variables on each bus.

Any ideas how to deal with it ?

Comment: Is it a matter of losing track of which bus is which within the render callback?

Comment: I'm moving to kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixMixer , seems better for my purpose

Comment: How did kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixMixer work out?  Post your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with kAudioUnitSubType_MatrixMixer. It allows to have any number of inputs and any number of outputs. 
So I'm setting buses 0-4 to output 0, buses 0-9 to output 1... etc. It's possible to set volume from any input to any output of the Matrix Mixer in this way:

```
 UInt32 element = (inputChannel<<16) | outputChannel;
 AudioUnitSetParameter(mixerMatrix, kMatrixMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Global, element, gain, 0);
```

With this method, all the buses are routed to the same mixer (MatrixMixer) and I can share variables in the render callback.